# HTML Circle with Icon and Text

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have to create a Circular Button with icon(PNG Icon) and Dynamic Text Inside it.

I am looking for a simple way to generate it in HTML_CSS (preferably CSS).
Features:

1. Change Inner Circle Fill Color by Simple CSS Class change (Pink, Blue, Gray)
2. Update Text displayed as required (Numbers/Count) by changing HTML Text
3. Trigger JS function on Click of Button

[Added Simple Rough Paint Mockup Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SDp3.png)

I tried looking for existing solutions:

- Trying To Combine : [Circles with Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131507/scalable-circles-with-dynamic-numbers-inside) and [Circles with Icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166010/middle-aligning-icon-fonts-inside-css-circles)

Unable to get Solution that has both of them ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include details of what you have tried so far and the code you used in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what you are doing and be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple HTML and CSS Can do. You need font-awesome library to make use of awesome ICONS.
Here is my try for your question

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>


.btn {
  display:block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- For dynamic button values you can add some functions -->
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> Clicks</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked Great... (Made Couple of CSS Style to adjust the Size and Position of Text, Background Colors as Required)